# ffmpeg segment muxer : rejoin segments to get back input video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

For a given video file (mp4 format), a m3u8 file which points to segments with some duration can be generated as follows :

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_list intermediate.m3u8 -segment_time <duration> intermediate_%03d.ts
```

If I were to rejoin the segments back,

```
ffmpeg -i intermediate.m3u8 -c copy output.mp4
```

will the output video be the same as input video?

A quick test tells me it is not the same (compared the sha256 sums).

Can anyone explain this specific behavior? Am I required to add particular flags to get back the original input video file or is it something else?

Comment: The streams will be the same - the timestamps may be slightly different due to rounding. Original metadata will be gone.

Comment: @Gyan Is there a way to check if the video stream is same? In case of audio stream, I  can dump the audio from the both input and output video file in wav format and compare their checksums.

Comment: You can run `-c copy raw.h264` on both files to check video streams.

Comment: @Gyan If were to compare the checksums of `raw.h264` file obtained from input video file and output video file, ideally they should be the same?

Comment: @Gyan Using md5 muxer I compared the video streams and they produce the same md5 however If I compare it using a external utility like md5sum, the md5 don't match

Comment: The md5 muxer only compares the checksums of the concatenated video packets; any metadata or encapsulation is discarded. md5sum won't know to do that.

Comment: @Gyan Thank you for answering my questions. It will be quite helpful if you can answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62474057/10155936) question too.