# FFmpeg: MD5 hash of M3U8 playlists generated from same input video with different segment durations (after applying video filter) don't match

Tags: video, ffmpeg, md5, http-live-streaming

Here are a few commands I am using to convert and transize a video in MP4 format to a [M3U8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#M3U8) playlist.

For a given input video (MP4 format), generate multiple video segments with segment duration 30 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i input.mp4 -dn -sn -an -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -copyts -start_at_zero -f segment -segment_time 30 30%03d.mp4 -dn -sn -vn -c:a copy audio.aac
```

Apply a video filter (in this case scaling) on each segment and convert it to a M3U8 format.

```
ls 30*.mp4 | parallel 'ffmpeg -loglevel error -i {} -vf scale=-2:144 -hls_list_size 0 {}.m3u8'
```

Store the list of m3u8 files generated in `list.txt` in this format `file 'segment-name.m3u8'`

```
for f in 30*.m3u8; do echo "file '$f'" >> list.txt; done
```

Using concat demuxer, combine all segment files (which are in M3U8 format) and the audio to get one final m3u8 playlist pointing to segments with duration of 10 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -f concat -i list.txt -i audio.aac -c copy -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 10 output_30.m3u8
```

---

I can change the segment duration in the first step from 30 seconds to 60 seconds, and compare the MD5 hash of the final M3U8 playlist generated in both the cases using this command:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i <input m3u8 playlist> -f md5 -
```

The MD5 hash of the output files differ, i.e., video streams of `output_30.m3u8` and `output_60.m3u8` are not the same.

Can anyone elaborate on this?

(*I expected the MD5 hash to be the same*)

Answer (score 0):

An M3U8 file is just a text file. Run diff on them, and it will tell you exactly what is different.

Comment: I am interested in comparing the video streams that the m3u8 files are pointing to not the m3u8 file itself. In this case I am comparing two m3u8 playlists (`output_30.m3u8` and `output_60.m3u8`) which were generated from the same input video but segmented with different segment durations (30s and 60s).

Comment: Yeah, of course it’s going to be different. Every segment begins with a PMT and PAT. Different segment durations, different table placements.

Comment: ok, but when I concat all the segments after applying the same video filter shouldn't the md5 of `output_30.m3u8` and `output_60.m3u8` be the same?

Comment: If I didn't apply  the video filter, the md5 (from md5 muxer) of the m3u8 playlists is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-crf 0`  (which implies lossless encoding) in the second step, gives the same checksums.

In case of lossy encoding, from what I have learnt so far, segmented encodes are bound to be different from normal encodes due to threads (quality differs as more threads are used) and lossy codec. Even with options such as `--stitchable` (x264 parameter) and `--threads 1` (FFmpeg output option), the checksum differs.